# Return Nonidentical elements of a Child class Constant array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Parent` class that has a Constant Array defined as `COLUMNS`

```
class Parent
  COLUMNS = [
    { column: 'type', type: 'String' }
  ]
end
```

And a `Child` class with the same Constant name called `COLUMNS`

```
class Child < Parent
  COLUMNS = [
    { column: 'type', type: 'String' },
    { column: 'user', type: 'String' },
    { column: 'password', type: 'String' }
  ]
end
```

How to fetch only the Nonidentical elements of a `Child` class Constant Array from that of `Parent` class Constant Array. i.e.,

```
# Expected output

[
  { column: 'user', type: 'String' },
  { column: 'password', type: 'String' }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Parent
  COLUMNS = [
    { column: 'type', type: 'String' }
  ]

  def self.fields
    COLUMNS
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  COLUMNS = [
    { column: 'type', type: 'String' },
    { column: 'user', type: 'String' },
    { column: 'password', type: 'String' }
  ]

  def self.fields
    COLUMNS - super
  end

  fields
end
```

Output:

```
=> [{:column=>"user", :type=>"String"}, {:column=>"password", :type=>"String"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just substract one from the other:

```
CHILD_COLUMNS = [
  { column: 'type', type: 'String' },
  { column: 'user', type: 'String' },
  { column: 'password', type: 'String' }
]
PARENT_COLUMNS = [
  { column: 'type', type: 'String' }
]

COLUMNS = CLIENT_COLUMNS - PARENT_COLUMNS
#=> [{:column=>"user", :type=>"String"}, {:column=>"password", :type=>"String"}]
```